Is my analysis of an audio amplifier correct?

This circuit is my electronics project, the BJT part is an amplifier and the voltage follower op amp just turn the high impedance voltage to a lower impedance.
I needed to get the experimental gain from the lap which was -29.08 V then solve it analytically to find the gain by hand and they should be kind of similar but it does not matter how much I try I can not get it any closer to -29.08 V. I want any help to identify my problem.
My solution technique:
(β=200)
First I start with DC analysis then assume it is in active mode, then try to simplify the circuit by applying Thevenin theorem if applicable then use the rule <<Ie =(β + 1) *Ib>> then apply KVL on the base and emitter to find another equation to have two equation of two unknowns and solve them to find Ib and Ie then calculate Ic then prove the active mode assumption then go to AC-Analysis and use the π-model then calculate Gm then Rπ then find the value for the Vout then divide it over the Vin (which is given).
is the logic itself wrong? as this is what I learned in college.
This is my answer:
DC-Analysis
Assume in active mode (all capacitors are open circuit). Simplifying using Thevenin
                 Rth = (R1xR4)/(R1+R4)= 2/3K ohm
                 Vth =Vcc x (R4/(R4+R1)) = 5/3V

using the rule:      Ie = (β+1) x Ib
Applying KVL on the base-emitter:
                -Vth + Rth x Ib + Vbe + R5 x Ie -Vee =0        
                (-5/3)+(2/3)x10^3xIb +0.7+10^3x201xIb-5=0 

Ib = 2.95 x 10^-5       //      Ie =5.94 x 10^-3       //    Ic = Ie - Ib = 5.91 x 10^-3
//then I should prove the active mode assumption but I am not going to write, but I did the prove. //
AC-Analysis
           (Vt = 26 x 10^-3)
            gm = Ic/Vt = 0.227
            rπ = β / gm = 878.75 ohm

then calculate Vout:
Vout = -gm x Vbe x (R3//R2)      (I need Vbe)
            Vbe = ((rπ//Rth)/(rπ//Rth)+R6) x Vin     (Vin = 40 x 10^-3 V)
            Vbe = 0.0109 V 
            Vout = -2.061 V
            Vout/Vin = -51.54 V

//I am deeply sorry for not writing everything from scratch but this is my first time writing equations using a keyboard, still I am really sorry if it made harder for you//
//to remind you the experimental gain is -29.02//
The difference is too big to be something like internal resistance or wire and connections and whatever.
This is my solution for the circuit, I would be so thankful if someone can tell how to fix it.

A very warm welcome to the site :-) On your schematics, never join 4 nets with a junction dot. Move the connections along so all junctions are T-junctions. Reason is that schematics with small dots, or poor prints of schematics, can make it unclear if there's a dot there. So a '+'-junction may be two nets crossing over or really a 4-way junction. If you don't use 4-way junctions ever, the net connections are clear and unambiguous. It's a good policy, established long ago, and pretty easy to do when drawing them. Thanks and, again, welcome.

You keep adding V to the gain values, but gain is unitless, when you divide volts by volts the units cancel out.

This is not operating in the small-signal regime with a 40 mV input. So, your analysis is mostly not very accurate.

What voltages do you mean I would appreciate if you can pin them . And the gain part is not logical that the unit V is going to get cancelled when dividing Vout/Vin?

In a common emitter amplifier the gain is usually taken as the impedance in the collector circuit divided by the impedance in the emitter circuit. In the case where there’s the impedance of the emitter bypass capacitor is negligible the transistor’s internal emitter impedance is used. The collector impedance will be the collector resistor in parallel with the load impedance.
You also have to take losses in the input and output circuits into account. For example there is a 1k resistor in series with the input signal and the input impedance of the amplifier is going to be less than that, so you can’t use 40 mV as the input voltage, you have to use the voltage on the amplifier side of that resistor. That alone with your other calculations might get you to the value you are looking for.
Also on the transistor output you added a high impedance input buffer and then hung a 5k resistor across it, so this will affect the overall gain as well.
If you really need the gain to be close to a specific value then making an amplifier with much more gain than needed and employing negative feedback is one way to do it, this is basically what an opamp does so the gain is only dependent on a resistor ratio.

Doing a SPICE analysis on this circuit, the gain is 28.62 dB (26.98x). If you get rid of the input resistor as Godjihyo suggests, the gain is 38.10 dB (80.35x). Thus, get rid of the input resistor and increase the AC emitter resistance (place a resistor in series with C3). This is a form of negative feedback. This will improve the gain stability over temperature and increase the input resistance.

Your first calculation of \$V_{TH}\$ is incorrect. There may be other errors, but that's moot, since they would all compound upon this initial error.
\$V_{TH}\$ will depend on both \$V_{CC}\$ and \$V_{EE}\$, yet \$V_{EE}\$ does not appear in your expression:
$$ V_{TH} = V_{CC}\frac{R_4}{R_1+R_4} $$
This assumes that the bottom end of R4 is connected to ground, 0V, which is not the case. The voltage divider R1 & R4 has potential difference \$V_{CC}-V_{EE}\$ across it. The voltage across R4 will be some fraction of this total potential difference, not a fraction of \$V_{CC}\$ alone.
Also, \$V_{EE}\$ sets the potential at the lower end of R4, to which the voltage across R4 should be added to obtain potential \$V_{TH}\$, an offset so to speak.
This is the correct expression for \$V_{TH}\$, representing base potential, and you can proceed from here:
$$ V_{TH} = V_{EE} + (V_{CC}-V_{EE}) \frac{R_4}{R_1 + R_4} $$
This same reasoning can be applied to any (unloaded) resistor potential divider with arbitrary potentials at each end.

Here's a derivation of \$V_{TH}\$, arriving at this same conclusion with more rigour:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Ohm's law:
$$V_{R1} = IR_1 $$
$$V_{R4} = IR_4 $$
KVL around the whole loop, starting at the ground symbol, and going clockwise:
$$ 0V + V_1 - V_{R1} - V_{R4} + V_2 = 0V $$
Find \$I\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_1 - V_{R1} - V_{R4} + V_2 &= 0V \\ \\
V_1 - IR_1 - IR_4 + V_2 &= 0V \\ \\
IR_1 + IR_4 &= V_1 + V_2 \\ \\
I(R_1 + R_4) &= V_1 + V_2 \\ \\
I &= \frac{V_1 + V_2}{R_1 + R_4}
\end{aligned}
$$
Substitute \$I\$ in the Ohm's law equation for \$R_4\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R4} &= IR_4 \\ \\
&= \frac{V_1 + V_2}{R_1 + R_4}R_4 \\ \\
&= (V_1 + V_2) \frac{R_4}{R_1+R_4} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Assign absolute potentials \$V_{EE}\$, \$V_{CC}\$ and \$V_{TH}\$, in terms of those potential differences, using KVL. First the power supplies:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{CC} &= 0V + V_1 \\ \\
V_1 &= V_{CC} \\ \\
V_{EE} &= 0V - V_2 \\ \\
V_2 &= -V_{EE} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now output TH:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{TH} &= V_{EE} + V_{R4} \\ \\
&= V_{EE} + (V_1 + V_2) \frac{R_4}{R_1+R_4} \\ \\
&= V_{EE} + (V_{CC} - V_{EE}) \frac{R_4}{R_1+R_4}
\end{aligned}
$$
As I mentioned before, this can be generalised to work for any resistor voltage divider with arbitrary potentials \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$ at each end:

simulate this circuit
$$ V_X = V_B + (V_A-V_B)\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} $$

Or, get rid of the split supply concept when doing the calculations for the transistor amplifier section. Much easier to use a single supply for the calculations.

@qrk True, but I felt that OP's assumption about $V_{TH}$ is a symptom of a deeper misconception, which I try to redress.

You can refer to this answer for some details. But, in short, I would quickly find the following:

\$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{+5\:\text{V}\,\cdot\,1\:\text{k}\Omega+\left(-5\:\text{V}\right)\,\cdot\,2\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega\,+\,2\:\text{k}\Omega}=-\frac53\:\text{V}\$
\$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{1\:\text{k}\Omega\,\cdot\,2\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega\,+\,2\:\text{k}\Omega}=\frac23\:\text{k}\Omega\$
\$I_{_\text{B}}=\frac{-\frac53\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}-\left(-5\:\text{V}\right)}{\frac23\:\text{k}\Omega+\left(\beta=200 + 1\right)\,\cdot\,1\:\text{k}\Omega}\approx 13.06\:\mu\text{A}\$
\$I_{_\text{C}}=200\,\cdot\,13.06\:\mu\text{A}\approx 2.612\:\text{mA}\$
\$r_{\text{e}}^{\:'}=\frac{V_T=26\:\text{mV}}{I_{_\text{C}}=2.612\:\text{mA}}\approx 10\:\Omega\$
Before input attenuation and output attentuation, \$A_v^{\:'}=\frac{1\:\text{k}\Omega}{10\:\Omega\,+\,0.2\:\Omega}\approx 98\$
Input attentuation, \$\frac{\frac23\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega\,+\,\frac23\:\text{k}\Omega}=0.4\$
Output attenuation, \$\frac{5\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega\,+\,5\:\text{k}\Omega}=\frac56\$
Expected combined voltage gain, \$A_v=0.4\,\cdot\,98\,\cdot\,\frac56\approx 33\$

This discounts the bulk base impedance of the BJT (but includes the emitter bulk impedance of the 2N2222 in the model) and excludes the Early Effect, as well. So I would expect to see a lower value with the Spice simulation. But not a lot lower. Maybe 10% or so. So about \$A_v\approx 29.7\$ with a simulation.
Note: I used \$0.2\:\Omega\$ as the bulk impedance at the emitter, taking from a model I see in LTspice for the 2N2222. And I also used \$700\:\text{mV}\$ as a very loose approximation for \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$.

How did you calculate the gain by only using resistance and I do not really think I am allowed to use the 0.2Ω as the professor did not mention such solution , and what is the " re` " .  Thanks for answering.

@dead rat - I understand your question. The quantity called re is nothing else than the inverse transconductance (re=1/gm), which I have used in my calculation. Let me add that I am strictly against this terminology because re is neither a resistance nor belongs it to the emitter (unfortunately, some authors call it "intrinsic emitter resistance").  I think it is much better to use the term transconductance gm because it is a very descriptive parameter: It is the slope of the Ic=f(Vbe) curve.

@periblepsis - just one short comment: Did you forget (or intentionally neglect) the dynamic input resistance hie at the base node?

@deadrat $r_e^{:'}$ is just another way of expressing the dynamic slope at the DC operating point.

@LvW I'm very well aware you don't like $r_e^{:'}$ from discussions several years ago about the student manual for AofE method of explanation. (See your own comments below here for example.)

@periblepsis - in this context, may I ask you: What do you think about the quoted Fig. N5.3 in Jonks answer as ca be seen in the link you have mentioned?

@periblepsis - I would like to explain why I find the usage of re instead of 1/gm so misleading (as we can see, the TO also had problems understanding it). Is there any justification for this misleading notation?  Frequently, some beginners have even mistakenly believed that re is a real resistor which also can cause negative feedback (see the visual representation in the above mentioned Fig. N5.3).

Here comes my (rough) calculation in short (assuming Vcc=+10V against ground):

Base DC voltage Vb=10V*(1/3)=3.33V

Emitter DC voltage: Ve=3.33-0.7=2.6V

Currents Ic=Ie=2.6V/1k=2.6mA

Transconductance gm=2.6mA/26mV=0.1 S

Gain (referred to base node): Av*=-gm(R3||R2)=-0.1*830=-83,

Base input resistance hie=beta/gm=2k

Total input resistance rin=hie||R1||R4=0.57k

Total gain: Av=Av*[rin/(rin+R6)]=-83*0.57/1.57=-30.2


Comment: The DC base current was neglected against the DC current through R1 (13µA<<3mA)

Why did you make the Vcc = 10V assumption ? I mean he already listed the Vcc = 5 .

@dead rat - the circuit under discussion shows a total DC voltage of 10V (between +5V and -5v). That´s what only matters. For a quick calculation of the DC operating point (and a good understanding of the various steps) it is more convenient to use only one single supply against common ground. The results are - of course - the same.

It is pretty convenient honestly. But is it okay to combine both voltages in one and replace the other with a ground? I am sorry if my question is really basic this my first semester in engineering and my first dealing with such circuits and electronics.

@dead rate - yes, it really does not matter. The only thing what matters is the total potential difference - called "voltage". When we write "+5V" we mean "against virtual ground". The same applies to the "-5V" supply. In some cases, it makes sense to use two DC sources (opamp usage). This is when we want that the output DC voltage to be be 0V (no coupling capacitor) because the signal to be amplified is referenced to the common ground. In the circuit under discussion there is a coupling capacitor at the output - hence the "real" DC potential at the collector does not matter for signal gain.
